# What is xmath.h for?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, include, math.h

While trying to get some older code (probably from around 2001-2005 or so) to build, i cam across the following conditional include:

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1300
#include <xmath.h>
#endif
```

I am currently building with Visual Studio 2012:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.61030 for x86
```

which gives a fatal error on this include:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xmath.h': No such file or directory
```

So to me, this looks like a non-standard Microsoft specific header that was supported from _MSC_VER 1300 (MSVC++ 7.0) on, but is currently no longer supported.  My questions are:

1. Is my assumption correct?  If 'yes', from what version of MSVC++ is this header no longer supported?
2. What is the purpose of including the `xmath.h` header?  My code compiles fine without it, so I can probably just leave it out?
3. Is `xmath.h` documented somewhere?  I cannot seem to find any decent documentation on it using a simple Google search.

Answer (score 0):

xmath.h is part of the internal implementation of Microsoft's standard C++ library. There is no reason for your code to use it. If your code compiles fine without it, dump it.

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I thought.  Dumped the include and happy about it :-)